# How to update a string that represents a map/level; trying to write a sokoban game

Tags: java, 2d

So I am having all types of trouble trying to design/think about how this can be done. To display the idea better, I have something like this:

```
private String level =
      "#########\n"
    + "#     ..#\n"
    + "#       #\n"
    + "#       #\n"
    + "#   $ $ #\n"
    + "#       #\n"
    + "#  @    #\n"
    + "#########\n";
```

And I want to, for example, move the @ up.

I want to keep it as simple as possible as it seems Im not able to do this, I thought about several ideas:

1. If I know the dimension of the String I can treat it as an matrix or vector and simply do math (a 4x4 matrix I can add simply add 6 to the original position (2,2) to be 1 row below)
2. I can make every line a string so it's somehow easier to move up and down
3. This would be completly innefficient I think but I could make a single for loop where everything is printed everytime, so everything is "built" every time anything changes.

The thing is that I just don't see how to update the string. I can think of the operations to know what should be moved and where, but I am either missing a concept or knowledge or is the wrong approach because I can't think of a way of translating the concept of: now delete this character in this position, and write this character in this other position.

Worst part is I found 2 (I think) very good examples of code, but still can't see where they are updating the image:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagamestutorial/sokoban/

[my 2D game, Sokoban, is working, but I want to know if I improve the design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319492/my-2d-game-sokoban-is-working-but-i-want-to-know-if-i-improve-the-design)

Comment: Why not just create a matrix?

Comment: I believe it cannot be done easier than you desribed: delete the character to be moved from the string and print it to the desired position.

Comment: I think when I tried it with a matrix I messed up the thinking somewhere, couldn't see how to move a "character" and a "box" at the same time, while also taking into account the rest of the possible options (like internal walls and the "goal" or final destination").

Like I'm sure it can be done, I couldn't think of a way of not messing it up.

As for printing the desired position, how do I modify a string on the go? Like, instead of printing absolutly everything every time?

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a class called `Level`, which internally may (up to you) represent the level as two-dimensional array of enums, lets call the enum `Tile`.

The enum then may look like:

```
public enum Tile {
    WALL('#'),
    EMPTY(' '),
    FEATURE1('.'),
    FEATURE2('$'),
    FEATURE3('@');

    private final char symbol;

    private Tile(final char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    public char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }
}
```

Now you can add methods to the `Level` that either return the level as a string (looping over the 2-d array and calling `getSymbol()` and every `Tile`, or one that directly prints it.

And to answer your question, now you can easily add a method that moves a certain cell up or switches cells, etc.

The answer is not to manipulate Strings, the answer is to think in OOP.

Comment: I'm ashamed to admit that I know what you mean, but don't know how to implement it. I've programmed things harder than this yet I can figure this out. So if you could tell me some about how to do the looping with that structure, it'd be of help.

Comment: I guess it's something like:

    for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
  // do what you want
}

But I'm not sure how to link that with the iteration through the String

Would using another structure like a hashmap or something or an arraylist be more usefull, when we talk about updating the values of the "level"?